# Deleting photos from iPhone which are already synced with my Mac

Tags: photos, iphone

How do I delete synced photos from my iPhone when the same photos are already deleted from my iMac and also the trash?

Comment: You have to define "synced photos" before others can help you. Are you syncing from iPhotos? Or a folder on your Mac? (By the way, I can't help you since I've turned on iCloud Photos; but when you provide the details someone else might. From my past experience though, synced photos should be deleted the next time you sync you phone.)

Comment: I'm syncing from a folder on my iMac through iTunes :)

Comment: Then from my past experience deleted photos should be cleared the next time you sync your phone with iTunes. Have you tried that?

Comment: yes, yes I have but it didn't work 

Comment: Sorry, then I have no idea. And IIRC you can only do that through iTunes; you can't delete those photos from your iPhone. Could you please try to disable photo syncing altogether from iTunes (uncheck Sync Photos), sync once, and re-enable it? I believe that should fix everything.

Comment: okay yup it did hehe sorry for the late reply! thank you so much ksh !

Comment: Glad it helped. I've turned that into an answer so that this question will be purged from the "no answers" queue.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, if photos are synced through iTunes to an iPhone from a Mac folder, iTunes should automatically take care of removing photos.

If that doesn't work, try to disable photo syncing first (uncheck "Sync Photos" in the iTunes-->iPhone-->Photos tab), sync the iPhone once, then turn on photo syncing again (by checking "Sync Photos").